# Unable to login with SSH after configure LDAP authentication

Tags: ldap, pam, sssd

I have a CoreOS server which i connected to my LDAP server. I get a correct answer after using *id* and *ldapsearch* commands. However, i still not able to login with SSH.

I can see on sssd_LDAP.log file that the server has received the request to login with the user (my_user), but the request was rejected.

```
tail -f /var/log/sssd/sssd_LDAP.log

(Sun Nov 13 15:06:29 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [acctinfo_callback] (0x0100): Request processed. Returned 0,0,Success (Success)
(Sun Nov 13 15:06:49 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [be_get_account_info] (0x0200): Got request for [0x1003][FAST BE_REQ_INITGROUPS][1][name=etcd]
(Sun Nov 13 15:06:49 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [sysdb_get_real_name] (0x0040): Cannot find user [etcd] in cache
(Sun Nov 13 15:06:49 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [acctinfo_callback] (0x0100): Request processed. Returned 0,0,Success (Success)
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:10 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [be_get_account_info] (0x0200): Got request for [0x1003][FAST BE_REQ_INITGROUPS][1][name=etcd]
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:10 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [sysdb_get_real_name] (0x0040): Cannot find user [etcd] in cache
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:10 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [acctinfo_callback] (0x0100): Request processed. Returned 0,0,Success (Success)
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:30 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [be_get_account_info] (0x0200): Got request for [0x1003][FAST BE_REQ_INITGROUPS][1][name=etcd]
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:30 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [sysdb_get_real_name] (0x0040): Cannot find user [etcd] in cache
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:30 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [acctinfo_callback] (0x0100): Request processed. Returned 0,0,Success (Success)
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:51 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [be_get_account_info] (0x0200): Got request for [0x1003][FAST BE_REQ_INITGROUPS][1][name=etcd]
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:51 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [sysdb_get_real_name] (0x0040): Cannot find user [etcd] in cache
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:51 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [acctinfo_callback] (0x0100): Request processed. Returned 0,0,Success (Success)
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:51 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [be_get_account_info] (0x0200): Got request for [0x3][BE_REQ_INITGROUPS][1][name=my_user]
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:51 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [sdap_initgr_nested_send] (0x0100): User entry lacks original memberof ?
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:51 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [acctinfo_callback] (0x0100): Request processed. Returned 0,0,Success (Success)
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:51 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [be_pam_handler] (0x0100): Got request with the following data
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:51 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): command: SSS_PAM_AUTHENTICATE
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:51 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): domain: LDAP
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:51 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): user: my_user
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:51 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): service: sshd
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:51 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): tty: ssh
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:51 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): ruser: 
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:51 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): rhost: x.x.x.x
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:51 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): authtok type: 0
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:51 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): newauthtok type: 0
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:51 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): priv: 1
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:51 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): cli_pid: 21280
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:51 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): logon name: not set
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:51 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [be_pam_handler_callback] (0x0100): Backend returned: (0, 7, <NULL>) [Success (Authentication failure)]
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:51 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [be_pam_handler_callback] (0x0100): Sending result [7][LDAP]
```

Does anyone know what is the issue?

---

**Update**: I have deleted the configuration files under /etc, as the default PAM config under /usr enables sssd.

Here are the current errors:

```
Dec 12 09:33:07 localhost sshd[3298]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=x.x.x.x user=my_user
Dec 12 09:33:07 localhost sshd[3298]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): received for user my_user: 7 (Authentication failure)
Dec 12 09:33:11 localhost sshd[3298]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=x.x.x.x  user=my_user
Dec 12 09:33:14 localhost sshd[3296]: PAM: Authentication failure for my_user from x.x.x.x
```

Here are the current configuration:

`cat system-auth`

```
    auth        required    pam_env.so
    auth        sufficient  pam_sss.so use_first_pass
    auth        sufficient  pam_unix.so try_first_pass likeauth nullok
    auth        required    pam_deny.so

    account     required    pam_unix.so
    # Don't fail if the user is unknown to sssd or if sssd isn't running
    account     required    pam_sss.so ignore_unknown_user ignore_authinfo_unavail
    account     optional    pam_permit.so

    password    sufficient  pam_unix.so try_first_pass  nullok sha512 shadow
    password    sufficient  pam_sss.so use_authtok
    password    required    pam_deny.so

    session     required    pam_limits.so
    session     required    pam_env.so
    session     required    pam_unix.so
    session     optional    pam_permit.so
    session     optional    pam_sss.so
    -session        optional        pam_systemd.so
```

`cat sshd`

```
auth       include  system-remote-login
account    include  system-remote-login
password   include  system-remote-login
session    include  system-remote-login
```

Answer (score 6):

According to this line:

```
(Sun Nov 13 15:07:51 2016) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): authtok type: 0
```

There was no password passed from the PAM stack towards SSSD (authtok type 0 means no password, 1 would be password), so there is nothign SSSD can use to authenticate towards the LDAP server.

I would recommend to check the PAM configuration (although I have never used coreos myself, so I have no idea how the PAM stack looks like there..)

Comment: Thanks . Please see the current issue above. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what your LDAP host is, assuming(yah I know) that is Active Directory this may not be the exact fix, when you try to login with ssh you need to specify the host and the username so the credential check isn't presumed to be against local credentials. In the case of AD  your ssh username would be AD\username.

You should provide information about the host(s) you are using LDAP to query the credentials from and check the logs on those system(S)to see if the query is reaching that host and if an error is being generated.